# Eclipse 3.6.2, Linux Ubuntu 11.04 - 64 bit system installed Mercurial and issues with HG

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

Can anyone tell me how to fix this `MercurialEclipse` install issue (1.8.3) - I also get this when I try to do software update in `Eclipse` (I am on a `64 bit` system):

Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable

```
com.intland.hgbinary.win32.feature.group [1.6.4.v201011161842]
```

cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.

Here is the image of the issue - can not get it to show here in this post.  Thanks in advance for help.

[a link](http://www.diskhero.com/images/eclipse.gif)!

Comment: You would be best off contacting the mercurialeclipse developers directly, I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Don't choose that option while you are chosing the packages to install in Eclipse Manager. That is only for Windows.

But after continue, I advise you to install first the Mercurial in your system. And it must be the version 1.5.0 otherwise the plugin won't work.

This is what I had to do, to have the last mercurial version in Ubuntu:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mercurial